# Laravel jobs dont run asynchron

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

My Laravel Version 10, Jobs do not run asynchron. (The job gets executed but synchron)

This is my setup:

php artisan queue:table was run 
php artisan queue:work runs

.env

QUEUE_CONNECTION=database

jobname.php

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use App\Mail\PasswordResetMail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;

class SendNewPasswordResetEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $incoming;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct($incoming)
    {
        $this->incoming = $incoming;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        sleep(2);
        Mail::to($this->incoming['sendTo'])->send(new PasswordResetMail(['resetLink' => $this->incoming['resetLink'], 'username' => $this->incoming['username']]));

    }
}
```

jobcall: (i tried these two ways of calling it. -> same result: doews't run anynchron.)

```
dispatch(new SendNewPasswordResetEmail(['sendTo' => $userInputs['email'], 'resetLink' =>  $url, 'username' => $user->username]));
SendNewPasswordResetEmail::dispatch(['sendTo' => $userInputs['email'], 'resetLink' =>  $url, 'username' => $user->username])->onQueue('jobs');
```

phpunit.xml

```
<env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="database"/>
```

config/queue.php

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'database'),
```

migration:

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('queue')->index();
        $table->longText('payload');
        $table->unsignedTinyInteger('attempts');
        $table->unsignedInteger('reserved_at')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedInteger('available_at');
        $table->unsignedInteger('created_at');
    });
}
```

Also if i check the jobs tabel in the database i don't see any jobs listed.

Comment: I also have Xdebug running if important

Comment: what's the output for `php artisan queue:work --status`?

Comment: Check this thread it might help to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42599055/8630903

Comment: Just to check the basic stuff you haven't explicitly clarified: 1) What do you mean by "*synchron*" - that your browser pauses the 2s because of the sleep? 2) Does the email actually get sent OK? 3) Do you cache your config, and if so have you tried clearing that with `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: php artisan config:clear 
did work!
Thanks a lot.

This is what i did:

php artisan queue:work --status
outputs:
  The "--status" option does not exist.

Also
php artisan queue:work --verbose
does not output anything. 

By synchron i mean that the code runs like it was running with the default setting:
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync

The Email gets send OK.

after i ran 
php artisan config:clear
output
   INFO  Configuration cache cleared successfully.

Comment: Glad you solved it. You should never cache config, routes, or anything in development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the command

```
php artisan config:clear
```

did work.

After that I get two Jobs in the SQL jobs table as expected.

Comment: If you cache your config, changes to `.env` files are not picked up.  You probably started with `QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync`, then cached your config, then changed `QUEUE_CONNECTION` in your `.env` - but that change was ignored because you have cached the config.  You should never cache anything in development, for exactly this reason - only in production. 
 https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/configuration#configuration-caching

Comment: PS - SO is not a forum, there are only answers and questions.  I've edited your post here so it is an answer - if you actaully want to ask another question, ask a new question.  If you want to add new info to the original queston, edit it and add info.  And please upvote/accept your own answer to help future visitors: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score -1):

Try with `QUEUE_CONNECTION` on redis; it will work.

Comment: I am confused, can you please explain how will this solution work to the question asked?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).